# Assumptions on inputs Gaussian Process Regression

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, gaussian-process, kernel-trick

Let $F:\mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ a function one seeks to approximate. You have $N$ observations of this function and you want to predict the value at some other points. In the Gaussian Process Regression framework, does one assume that the inputs $X\in\mathcal{X}$ follow a Gaussian random distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gaussian process is a generalization normal distribution, where the $\boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ are functions of the inputs $\mathbf{x}$. This makes the resulting Gaussian process is a distribution over functions since the realization of each such function of $\mathbf{x}$ is a random variable distributed according to a Gaussian distribution.

$$
\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
f(x_1) \\
f(x_2) \\
\vdots \\
f(x_N) \\
\end{array}} \right] \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma})
= \mathcal{GP}\left(m(\mathbf{x}),\, k(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}')\right)
$$

This formulation says nothing about the distribution of the $\mathbf{x}$'s.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I thought.